# Corrupt .docx files when using a PHP IMAP class

Tags: php, imap

I'm Using this PHP IMAP Class: http://code.google.com/p/php-imap/source/browse/trunk/ImapMailbox.php on a current project. After a few modifications the class is working. However whenever the class downloads .docx files they are always corrupt and have to be recovered by office.

```
    protected function initMailPart(IncomingMail $mail, $partStruct, $partNum) {
    $data = $partNum ? $this->imap_fetchbody($this->mbox, $mail->mId, $partNum, FT_UID) : $this->imap_body($this->mbox, $mail->mId, FT_UID);

    if($partStruct->encoding == 1) {
        $data = $this->imap_utf8($data);
    }
    elseif($partStruct->encoding == 2) {
        $data = $this->imap_binary($data);
    }
    elseif($partStruct->encoding == 3) {
        $data = $this->imap_base64($data);
    }
    elseif($partStruct->encoding == 4) {
        $data = $this->imap_qprint($data);
    }
    $data = trim($data);

    $params = array();
    if(!empty($partStruct->parameters)) {
        foreach($partStruct->parameters as $param) {
            $params[strtolower($param->attribute)] = $param->value;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($partStruct->dparameters)) {
        foreach($partStruct->dparameters as $param) {
            $params[strtolower($param->attribute)] = $param->value;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($params['charset'])) {
        $data = iconv($params['charset'], $this->serverEncoding, $data);
    }

    // attachments
    if($this->attachmentsDir) {
        $filename = false;
        $attachmentId = $partStruct->ifid ? trim($partStruct->id, " <>") : null;
        if(empty($params['filename']) && empty($params['name']) && $attachmentId) {
            $filename = $attachmentId . '.' . strtolower($partStruct->subtype);
        }
        elseif(!empty($params['filename']) || !empty($params['name'])) {
            $filename = !empty($params['filename']) ? $params['filename'] : $params['name'];
            $filename = $this->decodeMimeStr($filename);
            $filename = $this->quoteAttachmentFilename($filename);
        }
        if($filename) {
            if($this->attachmentsDir) {
                $filepath = rtrim($this->attachmentsDir, '/\\') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
                file_put_contents($filepath, $data);
                $mail->attachments[$filename] = $filepath;
            }
            else {
                $mail->attachments[$filename] = $filename;
            }
            if($attachmentId) {
                $mail->attachmentsIds[$filename] = $attachmentId;
            }
        }
    }
    if($partStruct->type == 0 && $data) {
        if(strtolower($partStruct->subtype) == 'plain') {
            $mail->textPlain .= $data;
        }
        else {
            $mail->textHtml .= $data;
        }
    }
    elseif($partStruct->type == 2 && $data) {
        $mail->textPlain .= trim($data);
    }
    if(!empty($partStruct->parts)) {
        foreach($partStruct->parts as $subpartNum => $subpartStruct) {
            $this->initMailPart($mail, $subpartStruct, $partNum . '.' . ($subpartNum + 1));
        }
    }
}

protected function decodeMimeStr($string, $charset = 'UTF-8') {
    $newString = '';
    $elements = $this->imap_mime_header_decode($string);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
        if($elements[$i]->charset == 'default') {
            $elements[$i]->charset = 'iso-8859-1';
        }
        $newString .= iconv($elements[$i]->charset, $charset, $elements[$i]->text);
    }
    return $newString;
}
```

Comment: Double check the attachment format. Are those documents always attached by a specific email client (for example Microsoft Outlook?).

Comment: They are definitely .docx saved from office 2007 and it is the same when emails are sent from Gmail, Outlook 2007 and Hotmail

Comment: Good to know! Can you create a MD5 checksum before attaching and then after? Also does the file-size vary? Also I would save multiple versions of the file with different encodings just for testing purposes. I would smell something in there, but naturally it's hard to say just from quickly scanning the code. You have some decisions on empty charsets and such, probably there is some twitch in there.

Comment: Checksum before: 6e602939e6499b3a7489b219dd9c38ac Checksum After: f507fccc822e6bb37727bc6d0b8ebc9c (yep they are different!!) yeh i was thinking about charset strange thing is every other types of attachments are fine such as jpg, png, pdf even .doc

Comment: Try what happens if you zend a zipfile. Just a test (if you can spare the time). How will it behave?

Answer (score 1):

Try wading into the binary files with a good editor, both before and after the round-trip from IMAP, to see if there's something obvious. I've had similar problems where whitespace made its way into the PHP script (e.g. at the end of a file after the close ?> tag); most formats won't blink but .docx may get kicked into a recovery if there's whitespace left over at the end.